# Why won't this swift code work properly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been learning swift for a short time and designed a simple ios swift app in xcode to open up an alert and display the developer name inside of a label when tapped. The code is posted below. For some reason, on the `label.hidden = true`, I get an error saying "expected declaration", but nothing else. Why is it getting this error message, and what does it mean?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//declares the label
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
//should hide the label
label.hidden = true
//next 2 lines center the label
label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)

label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
//puts text into the label
label.text = "This app was developed by me!"

//declares the function
@IBAction func function() {
    // declares variable that stores the alert and it's properties
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!", message: "Here is some information about the developer!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    label.hidden = false


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to encapsulate it with function.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureViews()
  }

  func configureViews() {
    //declares the label
    //should hide the label
    label.hidden = true
    //next 2 lines center the label
    label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)

    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    //puts text into the label
    label.text = "This app was developed by me!"
  }


  //declares the function
  @IBAction func function() {
    // declares variable that stores the alert and it's properties
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!", message: "Here is some information about the developer!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    label.hidden = false
  }
}
```